# Windows Azure - HttpListener - Worker Role

Tags: azure, listener, paypal-ipn

I would like to create a service listener in Azure, which should have an endpoint exposed, where http request can be made.

to be more specific, To implement a listener in azure for Paypal IPN.

Any thoughts / help is much appreciated and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's a very open question.  You can do this many ways, but there are three I'll mention here.  Since this is just a HTTP request coming in you can use Cloud Services, Windows Azure Websites or Virtual Machines.

If you use Cloud Services with a web role the HTTP 80 and 443 are already configured as endpoints (if you aren't using .NET you may need to make sure that the endpoints are configured in the service definition file you include in the package).  If you are writing this listener to be hosted inside IIS then you just need to deploy a web role as normal with your listener code built in.  There are many examples of creating web roles on the internet and in the Windows Azure Training Kit.

If you use Cloud Services with a worker role if your listener code is hosted in something else, such as a Windows Service or executable, then you'll need to be sure that the OnStart code of the worker role starts up your process (installing anything that needs to be installed via start up tasks).  Also, you'll need to configure the endpoint for 80 and/or 443 so that the request can be routed in.  Then the listener will need to listen on the local port you configure for the endpoint.  Again, there are many examples of setting up a worker role, though not as many that will talk about a listener on the worker role.

If you choose to use Windows Azure Web Sites I would recommend you go with the Standard version so that you get a dedicated VM and custom domain SSL support.  I say this only because you mention this is going to be for a payment endpoint.  Beyond the SSL support the shared and free have quotas around them that at some point may cause your payment call to be missed.  If you choose to go this route you can create the web site which hosts the endpoint as normal and deploy to the website.

Finally, you can also elect to run a Virtual Machine that you can install pretty much whatever you need and deploy to it very similarly to how you would deploy on premises or another hosted service provider like Rackspace.  This will be the most cumbersome to maintain because you'll be in charge of making sure all the patches and maintenance is taken care of on the VM.

I would suggest the Cloud Service or the Web Site with a potential lean towards the Cloud Service myself.  Use the VM route as a fall back if necessary (such as there is so much to install to deal with the requirements of the listener).

Note: I would do a LOT of research on compliance of this listener being hosted.  I'm not sure what information the IPN has in it, so if it has sensitive information such as payment card data you may fall under PCI or something like that which will cause you problems. Likely that information is actually hidden from you as a PayPal is the payment gateway, but I'd still want to research to verify you are okay.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'd prefer the Cloud Service with worker Role, as such the data returned doesn't seem to have any sensitive information, and just the status.